# ValidForm Builder file type validation

Tags: validform

Does anybody know how to validate the file type input.

I have modified (hard coded) the class.vf_file.php input.

```
$strOutput .= "<input accept=\".pdf,.doc,.docx\"     etc----/>\n";
```

This helps with Google Chrome, but Safari, Firefox ignore the modifications

Preventing users to submit the form if any other type of file is detected would be the ideal solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a third party file uploading library like [Plupload](http://plupload.com). We always use ValidForm Builder together with Plupload; works like a charm.

However you can use the `meta` array to implement custom attributes in the `<input>` tag without having to hardcode anything:

```
$objForm->addField(
    "upload-document", 
    "Upload Document", 
    ValidForm::VFORM_FILE,
    array(),  // Validation array
    array(),  // Error handling array
    array(    // Meta array
        "fielddata-extensions" => "pdf,doc,docx"
    )
);
```

By prefixing meta keys with the 'field' prefix, you add that specific meta to the `<input>` field itself instead of it's wrapping `<div class='vf__optional'></div>`

The above example will output:

```
<div class="vf__optional">
    <label for="upload-image">Upload Image</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152">
    <input type="file" value="" name="upload-image[]" id="upload-image" class="vf__file" data-extensions="pdf,doc,docx">
</div>
```

So using a combination of meta and a third party file upload handler, you can actually to pretty cool stuff.

That being said -- I must admit that the file upload field didn't get as much attention as the other field types lately.

Comment: Did it work for you @William? If so, please upvote my answer and mark it as the answer for your question.

Comment: Sorry for not giving any feedback on this one Robin. I did look into third party file upload handler, but this would have meant modifying to much of our project just before it went live.

Comment: It is left as is at the moment as other areas of our project took precedent over this issue. Server side security issues are dealt with with bespoke coding. We'll have to revisit this when we get more time available.